# How do I extract the type from a field?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2013, csom

In SharePoint Server side code, you can write something like:

```
field.fieldvalueType
```

Which will sometimes give you the type (DateTime, or whatever). Annoyingly, sometimes, it just returns Null (for example, the ID field).

In CSOM, you don't have that field. However, there's `TypeAsString` which gives  SharePoint types such as:

- Computed
- Integer
- Note

What I'd like to do is grab this [huge table from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.listitem.aspx):

And Extract "Int32" when I know that I'm dealing with an "Integer" field, and extract "System.String" from SharePoint's note.

This kinda works, but it's the mother of all hacks:

```
var myTempItem = list.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
myTempItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery();

context.Load(myTempItem);
context.ExecuteQuery();
```

After creation, you can use:

`myTempItemCreated[fieldImTryingToGetTypeOf.Title].GetType().FullName` -> Gives-> `System.Int32`

Now, what's the proper way to do it? I'm just hoping the answer isn't a ten foot long switch case statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since there is no [SPField.FieldValueType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.fieldvaluetype.aspx) counterparts in SharePoint CSOM API, the following extension method demonstrates how to perform it:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Field = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Field;

namespace SharePoint.Client.Extensions
{
    public static class FieldExtensions
    {


        public static Type GetFieldValueType(this Field field)
        {
            var table = new Dictionary<FieldType, Type>();
            table[FieldType.Guid] = typeof(Guid);
            table[FieldType.Attachments] = typeof(bool);
            table[FieldType.Boolean] = typeof(bool);
            table[FieldType.Choice] = typeof (string);
            table[FieldType.CrossProjectLink] = typeof(bool);
            table[FieldType.DateTime] = typeof(DateTime);
            table[FieldType.Lookup] = typeof(FieldLookupValue);
            table[FieldType.ModStat] = typeof(int);
            table[FieldType.MultiChoice] = typeof(string[]);
            table[FieldType.Number] = typeof(double);
            table[FieldType.Recurrence] = typeof(bool);
            table[FieldType.Text] = typeof(string);
            table[FieldType.URL] = typeof(FieldUrlValue);
            table[FieldType.URL] = typeof(FieldUrlValue);
            table[FieldType.User] = typeof(FieldUserValue);
            table[FieldType.WorkflowStatus] = typeof(int);
            table[FieldType.ContentTypeId] = typeof(ContentTypeId);
            table[FieldType.Note] = typeof(string);
            table[FieldType.Counter] = typeof(int);
            table[FieldType.Computed] = typeof(string);
            table[FieldType.Integer] = typeof(int);
            table[FieldType.File] = typeof(string);

            if (!table.ContainsKey(field.FieldTypeKind))
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Unknown field type: {0}", field.FieldTypeKind));
            return table[field.FieldTypeKind];
        }
    }
}
```

Usage

```
var list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listTitle);
var fields = list.Fields;
ctx.Load(fields);
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var field in fields)
{
    if (field.FieldTypeKind != FieldType.Invalid)
    {
         var fieldValueType = field.GetFieldValueType();
         Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", field.InternalName, fieldValueType);    
    }        
}
```

Comment: I guess, sometimes, there simply is no lazy way out. http://www.quote2day.com/wp-content/uploads/Photo-35.jpg

Comment: :) i also consider myself a lazy person, but in this particular case it seems to be the only way..

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @Vadim's answer, here is a version that does not construct a new dictionary every time the extension method is called;

```
namespace SharePoint.Client.Extensions
{
    public static class FieldExtensions
    {
        private static Dictionary<FieldType, Type> _fieldTypes = new Dictionary<FieldType, Type>()
        {
            { FieldType.Guid, typeof(Guid) },
            { FieldType.Attachments, typeof(bool)},
            {FieldType.Boolean, typeof(bool)},
            {FieldType.Choice, typeof(string)},
            {FieldType.CrossProjectLink, typeof(bool)},
            {FieldType.DateTime, typeof(DateTime)},
            {FieldType.Lookup, typeof(FieldLookupValue)},
            {FieldType.ModStat, typeof(int)},
            {FieldType.MultiChoice, typeof(string[])},
            {FieldType.Number, typeof(double)},
            {FieldType.Recurrence, typeof(bool)},
            {FieldType.Text, typeof(string)},
            {FieldType.URL, typeof(FieldUrlValue)},
            {FieldType.User, typeof(FieldUserValue)},
            {FieldType.WorkflowStatus, typeof(int)},
            {FieldType.ContentTypeId, typeof(ContentTypeId)},
            {FieldType.Note, typeof(string)},
            {FieldType.Counter, typeof(int)},
            {FieldType.Computed, typeof(string)},
            {FieldType.Integer, typeof(int)},
            {FieldType.File, typeof(string)}
        };

        public static Type GetFieldValueType(this Field field)
        {
            if (!_fieldTypes.ContainsKey(field.FieldTypeKind))
                throw new NotSupportedException(string.Format("Unknown field type: {0}", field.FieldTypeKind));
            return _fieldTypes[field.FieldTypeKind];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you need to do the mapping you describe, not the `myTempItemCreated[fieldImTryingToGetTypeOf.Title].GetType().FullName` 
method.

The reason is, `myTempItemCreated[fieldImTryingToGetTypeOf.Title].GetType().FullName`
will fail in the scenario where the field value (e.g. Title) is null for that particular ListItem object.  (While Title is not generally null, other fields can be and are null).  And obviously null does not give you an object on which you can call the GetType() method (you would get a NullReferenceException obviously).

So, for a general solution to the problem, one does indeed have to map the String returned from TypeAsString of the list field, calling from the list object / list field, and not from the list item.

Answer (score -1):

You can get the type of field using the following snippet:

```
item.Fields["Title"].FieldValueType.FullName
```

Comment: Sorry i'm confused as to what's required? Do you wish to get the value of the field? i,e: Just call a method to get the value and it returns the value based on it's type?

Comment: Sorry but the question is pretty clear. Your answer is *literally* the second line of the question (which is obviously really frustrating). I need to get the type of the field without creating a list item. Read the question as to an explanation of why your snippet does not work.